# Where are the Wine packages for BOSS Linux?

Tags: linux, wine

On the Wine website, I see different types of Operating Systems but cant find BOSS Linux. In which category does it fall? Is it listed under another name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOSS appears to be [derived from Debian](http://bosslinux.in/about-us), so the first thing you should do is check if WINE is already in their repositories -- it probably is:

```
apt-cache search wine
```

If not, you could try the debian one from the Wine site, but as it says:

> Warning: These are beta packages This means they will periodically
>   suffer from regressions, and as a result an update may break
>   functionality in Wine. If the latest stable release of Wine (currently
>   Wine 1.6) works for you, then you may not want to use these beta
>   packages.

So don't bother with that unless you can't download Wine directly from the BOSS repositories.  Unfortunately, if Wine is missing from the BOSS repositories, the version from the Wine site probably won't work.

Comment: COULD I ADD A DEBIAN REPO IN BOSS?

Comment: is my boss called debian unstable, sid, or wheezy?

Comment: I don't know.  There isn't much documentation on the BOSS site. 'unstable' refers to repos that are part of either 'sid' or 'wheezy'; i.e. there is a "sid unstable" and a "wheezy unstable".

Answer (score 1):

As [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharat_Operating_System_Solutions), BOSS is a Debian derivative, so maybe you can take Debian version of wine, if you really need an up-to-date one.

The BOSS' recommended version should be the one coming with BOSS, which [are available](http://packages.bosslinux.in/boss/pool/server/main/w/wine/) on BOSS repository.

Comment: COULD I ADD A DEBIAN REPO IN BOSS?